# Shifting Groupby In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate cumulative revenue by account. Here is some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'account_id': ['111','111','111','222','222','333','333','333','666','666'],
    'company': ['initech','initech','initech','jackson steinem & co','jackson steinem & co','ingen','ingen','ingen','enron','enron'],
    'cohort_period': [0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,0,1],
    'revenue':[3.67,9.95,9.95,193.29,299.95,83.03,499.95,99.95,1.52,19.95]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which outputs:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
  account_id  cohort_period               company  revenue
0        111              0               initech     3.67
1        111              1               initech     9.95
2        111              2               initech     9.95
3        222              0  jackson steinem & co   193.29
4        222              1  jackson steinem & co   299.95
5        333              0                 ingen    83.03
6        333              1                 ingen   499.95
7        333              2                 ingen    99.95
8        666              0                 enron     1.52
9        666              1                 enron    19.95
```

There are a ton of examples on how to do this, which is basically:

```
df['cumulative_revenue'] = df.groupby('account_id')['revenue'].cumsum()
```

*However*, here's the catch: in this data, revenue during Cohort Period 0 is prorated, which for purpose of my analysis I don't care about. What I need is to start the cumulative sum at Cohort Period 1. For example, the cumulative revenue for the Initech should look like:

```
0    nan
1    9.95
2    19.90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
# check valid cohort_period
valid_cohort = df.cohort_period.ne(0)

# cumulative sum revenue where cohort_period is not equal to zero and mask otherwise as nan
df['cum_revenue'] = valid_cohort.mul(df.revenue).groupby(df.account_id).cumsum().where(valid_cohort)

print(df)
#  account_id  cohort_period               company  revenue  cum_revenue
#0        111              0               initech     3.67          NaN
#1        111              1               initech     9.95         9.95
#2        111              2               initech     9.95        19.90
#3        222              0  jackson steinem & co   193.29          NaN
#4        222              1  jackson steinem & co   299.95       299.95
#5        333              0                 ingen    83.03          NaN
#6        333              1                 ingen   499.95       499.95
#7        333              2                 ingen    99.95       599.90
#8        666              0                 enron     1.52          NaN
#9        666              1                 enron    19.95        19.95
```

Answer (score 1):

I will create a new variable 'New'

```
df['New']=df.revenue
df.loc[df['cohort_period']==0,'New']=np.nan
df['cumulative_revenue']=df.groupby('account_id')['New'].cumsum()
df
Out[63]: 
  account_id  cohort_period               company  revenue     New  \
0        111              0               initech     3.67     NaN   
1        111              1               initech     9.95    9.95   
2        111              2               initech     9.95    9.95   
3        222              0  jackson steinem & co   193.29     NaN   
4        222              1  jackson steinem & co   299.95  299.95   
5        333              0                 ingen    83.03     NaN   
6        333              1                 ingen   499.95  499.95   
7        333              2                 ingen    99.95   99.95   
8        666              0                 enron     1.52     NaN   
9        666              1                 enron    19.95   19.95   
   cumulative_revenue  
0                 NaN  
1                9.95  
2               19.90  
3                 NaN  
4              299.95  
5                 NaN  
6              499.95  
7              599.90  
8                 NaN  
9               19.95
```

Or `mask`

```
df.groupby('account_id').apply(lambda x :x['revenue'].mask(x['cohort_period'].eq(0)).cumsum())
```